# How can I get only 1 result to be printed to the console and not both of them?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code here has a problem but I know what the problem is. There are 2 characters in grade, so 2 results are shown, each result is added by 0.3. That is a problem because only one result is supposed to be printed to the console.

```
keydict = {'A': 4.0,'B': 3.0,'C': 2.0,'D': 1.0,'F': 0, '+': 0.3, '-': -0.3}
grade = input('Grade:')


def letter2number(letter):
    if len(grade) > 2:
        print('Too many characters')
        letter2number(grade)
    for char in grade:
        if char in keydict:
            if '+' in grade:
                print(keydict[char] + keydict['+'])
            elif '-' in grade:
                print(keydict[char] + keydict['-'])
            else:
                print(keydict[char])
        else:
            print(grade,'is an invalid input')
    return


letter2number(grade)
```

This is what gets printed to the screen after the user inputs "A+"(or any grade with a '+' or '-') I realize the for loop is causing this problem because there are 2 characters in the input. But I don't think there is another way to do it without using a for loop. The 4.3 is expected, the 0.6 is not what I want.

```
Grade: A+ # <<< Thats a user input
4.3       # <<< YES
0.6       # <<< How can I get this to NOT print
```

Other than the 0.6 being printed, I have no other issue with the code. In other words, I don't want the 0.6 there, but the 4.3 should stay.

Comment: Well written question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `for` loop is unnecessary here, and causing your issue. Remember that the `for` loop is going to look at both characters independently

```
"A"  # evaluates to 4.0, add 0.3 since '+' exists in the string
"+"  # evaluates to 0.3, add 0.3 since '+' exists in the string
```

Which is definitely not what you want. What you should do instead is:

```
def lettertograde(letter):
    letter, *modifier = letter
    grade = keydict[letter]
    if "+" in modifier:
        grade += 0.3
    elif "-" in modifier:
        grade -= 0.3
    return grade
```

This `a, *b = ...` syntax is splat unpacking, and works by pulling parts out of an iterable like so:

```
a, *b = "A"          # a = "A", b = []
a, *b = "A+"         # a = "A", b = ["+"]
a, *b = "A-"         # a = "A", b = ["-"]
a, *b = "Good job!"  # a = "G", b = ["o", "o", "d", " ", "j", "o", "b", "!"]
a, *b = ""           # ValueError("not enough values to unpack (expected at least 1, got 0)")
```

N.B. that multiple splats in the same expression introduces ambiguity, and is not allowed.

```
a, *b, c, *d = "anything"  # SyntaxError("two starred expressions in assignment")
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! Never thought about `a, *b` technique regarding strings :)

Comment: I am a beginner at python and did not know about *modifier, thank you.

Comment: @iTadreik note that `modifier` is just the name of the variable. The magic is in the `*`.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> keydict = {'A': 4.0,'B': 3.0,'C': 2.0,'D': 1.0,'F': 0, '+': 0.3, '-':    0.3, ' ': 0.0}
>>> grade = input('Grade:') + ' '
>>> if grade[0] in keydict and grade[1] in keydict:
       print(grade, keydict[grade[0]]+ keydict[grade[1]])
    else:
       print(grade, 'is an invalid input')
```

B  3.0
banana  is an invalid input
B-  2.7

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `break` at the end of the block `if char in keydict:`

```
keydict = {'A': 4.0,'B': 3.0,'C': 2.0,'D': 1.0,'F': 0, '+': 0.3, '-': -0.3}
grade = input('Grade:')


def letter2number(letter):
    if len(grade) > 2:
        print('Too many characters')
        letter2number(grade)
    for char in grade:
        if char in keydict:
            if '+' in grade:
                print(keydict[char] + keydict['+'])
            elif '-' in grade:
                print(keydict[char] + keydict['-'])
            else:
                print(keydict[char])

            break  # <<---

        else:
            print(grade,'is an invalid input')
    return


letter2number(grade)
```

`break` stops the loop

Comment: As someone who is learning Python, why do you need a break here? Wouldn't it just finish the function? Where does it print the second value?

Comment: Ah think I've got you reasoning. But with the break wouldn't it return `4.0` and not the desired `4.3`?

Comment: `why do you need a break here?` - `break` breaks the loop. `Wouldn't it just finish the function?` - `break` does not finish the function, just stops loop and continue the execution of the rest code. `Where does it print the second value?` - you mean why the code produce the 2nd value in case of iTadreik? `But with the break wouldn't it return 4.0 and not the desired 4.3?` - the function will return 4.3 because of `if '+' in grade: print(keydict[char] + keydict['+'])`

Comment: Yes I did. Thanks for taking the time to explain. I understand was just mis-reading the syntax

Comment: @Tom , iTadreik's code prints the second value (0.6) because he implemented a loop `for char in grade:` -> there are 2 chars in `grade` (`A` and `+`). Loop works with every character, and at the 2nd iteration of the loop (when loop works with `+`) block `if '+' in grade:` executes `print(keydict[char] + keydict['+'])` (when `char` here is `+`). This is the reason why the 2nd result is 0.6.

Comment: Yup got it - they don't actually need the loop

Answer (score 0):

Generate the modified grades and add them to the dictionary. Then look up the entire grade string.

```
>>> keydict = {'A': 4.0, 'B': 3.0, 'C': 2.0, 'D': 1.0, 'F': 0}
>>> modifiers = {'+': 0.3, '-': -0.3}
>>> keydict.update({ k + mk: v + mv for k, v in keydict.items() for mk, mv in modifiers.items() })
>>> keydict
{'D': 1.0, 'F+': 0.3, 'A+': 4.3, 'F': 0, 'F-': -0.3, 'C+': 2.3, 'B': 3.0, 'C': 2.0, 'D-': 0.7, 'C-': 1.7, 'B-': 2.7, 'D+': 1.3, 'B+': 3.3, 'A-': 3.7, 'A': 4.0}
>>> grade = 'C-'
>>> keydict[grade]
1.7
```